# Am replacing the first occurrence of a string, how can I replace all occurrences?

Tags: c++, string, replace

I have already bulid the basic structure by using the loop + replace,In C++, the str.replace is only to replace single string, however, in some cases, we need to replace all the same string, My code can compile successfully and can output to the screen, but it seems that it does not replace successfully.

Thanks in advance

here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main(void)
{
    // initialize
    std::ofstream fout;
    std::ifstream fin;
    fout.open("cad.dat");
    fout <<  "C is a Computer Programming Language which is used worldwide, Everyone should learn how to use C" << std::endl;

    fin.open("cad.dat");
    std::string words;
    getline(fin,words);
    std::cout << words << std::endl;
 
    while(1)
    {
        std::string::size_type pos(0);
        if (pos = words.find("C") != std::string::npos && words[pos+1] != ' ') //the later one is used to detect the single word "C"
        {
            words.replace(pos, 1, "C++"); 
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << words;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save `pos` and use it for the following `find` operations but you currently initialize it to `0` every iteration in the `while` loop.

You could replace the while `while` loop with this for example:

```
for(std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    (pos = words.find("C", pos)) != std::string::npos; // start find at pos
    pos += 1)  // skip last found "C"
{
    if(pos + 1 == words.size() || words[pos + 1] == ' ')
        words.replace(pos, 1, "C++");
}
```

Note: This will replace the `C` in words ending with `C` too, for example an acronym like `C2C` will become `C2C++`. Also, a sentence ending with `C.` would not be handled. To handle these cases you could add a check for the character before the found `C` too and add punctuation to the check.

Example:

```
#include <cctype>   // isspace, ispunct
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string words = "C Computer C2C C. I like C, because it's C";
    std::cout << words << '\n';

    // a lambda to check for space or punctuation characters:
    auto checker = [](unsigned char ch) {
        return std::isspace(ch) || std::ispunct(ch);
    };

    for(std::string::size_type pos = 0;
        (pos = words.find("C", pos)) != std::string::npos;
        pos += 1)
    {
        if( (pos == 0 || checker(words[pos - 1])) &&
            (pos + 1 == words.size() || checker(words[pos + 1]))
        ) {
            words.replace(pos, 1, "C++");
        }
    }

    std::cout << words << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
C Computer C2C C. I like C, because it's C
C++ Computer C2C C++. I like C++, because it's C++
```

Answer (score 2):

You can **simplify** your program by just using `regex` as follows:

```
std::regex f("\\bC\\b");
words = std::regex_replace(words, f, "C++"); // replace "C" with "C++"
```

Then there is **no need** for a while loop as shown in the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main(void)
{
    // initialize
    std::ofstream fout;
    std::ifstream fin;
    fout.open("cad.dat");
    fout <<  "C is a Computer Programming Language which is used worldwide, Everyone should learn how to use C" << std::endl;

    fin.open("cad.dat");
    std::string words;
    getline(fin,words);
    std::cout << words << std::endl;
 
    std::regex f("\\bC\\b");
    words = std::regex_replace(words, f, "C++"); // replace "C" with "C++"

    std::cout << words;
}
```

Comment: This is nice but note that it replaces all `C`s, so `Computer` will become `C++omputer` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes indeed. Since computers doesn't know difference between a "word" and a substring, i guess we have to iterate manually(as you did) the string for replacing only the words and not the substrings.

Comment: Or one could expand on the regex idea. It should be possible to get that working too. I haven't used C++ regex much myself though. Perhaps I'll look into them more closely when/if they start supporting Perl regexes and get support for `constexpr` regexes.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have done that now. Check out my current(edited) answer.

Comment: Nice! You get my upvote for that!